# Abline not working with Linear regression Model

Tags: r

I have a data in R so i want to test the data on various models. I have split the data into 2 sets 80% training and 20% testing. So now what i want to do is train the training data set on a linear model and predict it on the testing data set.

I have don this so far.

```
temp<-lm(formula = cityMpg ~ peakRpm+horsePower+wheelBase , data=train)
temp_test<- predict(temp,test)
plot(temp_test)
```

Here, I get the scatter plot. Now I just want a line in this scatter plot.
    When I use abline(temp_test), I get an error.
    i WANT THE LINE as automatic, I do not wish to specify the co-ordinates.
    getting error as:

```
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
      invalid a=, b= specification
```

Comment: hi abline(temp) works but it works for the training data i want it for a test data

Warning message:
In abline(temp) : only using the first two of 4 regression coefficients

Comment: Plotting 4-dimensional data is not straightforward, at least not nearly as much as 2-d data. `abline` only works for simple linear models with 2 coefficients, 1 intercept and 1 slope.

Comment: You can't do that, you have a 4 dimensional model  and abline only works for 2d.

Comment: Ok. Then How can I plot a Line  ??? By lines() function ?

Comment: If I just use, temp<-lm(formula = cityMpg ~ peakRpm, data=train), then is it fine ?/

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above, this is  a bit tricky for a multi-dimensional model.

Get some data (you neglected to include a reproducible example: see http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ...)

```
library(foreign)
dat <- read.arff(url("http://www.cs.umb.edu/~rickb/files/UCI/autos.arff"))
```

Split into training and test data sets:

```
train <- dat[1:150,]
test <- dat[151:nrow(dat),]
```

The variable names are a bit awkward for R (the dashes are interpreted as minus operators, so we have to use back-quotes to protect the names):

```
fit <- lm(`city-mpg` ~ `peak-rpm`+horsepower+`wheel-base`,data=train)
temp_test <- predict(fit,test)
```

Plot the predictions vs peak RPM:

```
par(las=1,bty="l") ## cosmetic
plot(test[["peak-rpm"]],temp_test,xlab="peak rpm",ylab="predicted")
```

In order to add the line, we have to adjust the intercept according to some baseline values of the other parameters: we'll use the mean (another alternative is to center all the predictor variables before fitting the model):

```
cf <- coef(fit)
abline(a=cf["(Intercept)"]+
          mean(test$horsepower)*cf["horsepower"]+
          mean(test$`wheel-base`)*cf["`wheel-base`"],
          b=coef(fit)["`peak-rpm`"])
```

Another way to do this is to use `predict()`:

```
newdat <- with(test,
            data.frame(horsepower=mean(horsepower),
                       "wheel-base"=mean(`wheel-base`),
                       "peak-rpm"=seq(min(`peak-rpm`),
                                        max(`peak-rpm`),
                                        length=41),
                       check.names=FALSE))
newdat["city-mpg"] <- predict(fit,newdat)
with(newdat,lines(`peak-rpm`,`city-mpg`,col=4))
```

(41 points is silly for a straight line -- we could have used just 2 -- but will work well if you want to plot something curved, like confidence intervals or a nonlinear fit.)

Alternatively you could just fit the marginal model, but the actual fitted line is somewhat different (it will only be the same if all the predictors are orthogonal to each other):

```
fit2 <- lm(`city-mpg` ~ `peak-rpm`,data=train)
abline(fit2,col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. But what does predicted value tells here ? Does it tells cityMpg value ??? And in the table '-' is not there, the words are combined, so I do not face any issue regaring the space. Can u tell what does 



plot(test[["peak-rpm"]],temp_test,xlab="peak rpm",ylab="predicted")

represents, a graph of peak rpm and predicted value(what will be dis value)

Comment: (1) yes, the predicted value is the same as the response variable of the fitted model. (2) the plot puts peak RPM on the x axis and the predicted value of city MPG from the model on the y axis.

Comment: Oh, ok. Means if i want to predict cityMpg value from 3 attributes, then I cant do that. I can only predict its vaalue from one other attribute ?

Comment: if you want to predict `cityMpg` from 3 attributes **and draw the corresponding picture** then you need to make some decision about what values of the other (non-focal) attributes you are going to use to draw the picture.  You might want to explore the `effects` package ...